# lists under a description?

Tags: html, list, html-lists, dd

Am I doing something wrong? In this image, it appears as if the ol is part of the term 1 description, but on my coding it's not.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvPX5.png)

my code:

```
<dl>
    <dt>term 1 (definition list)</dt>
    <dd>term 1 description</dd>
</dl>
    <ol>
        <li>ol list item 1</li>
        <li>ol list item 2
            <ul>
                <li>ul list item 1</li>
                <li>ul list item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

thank you

Comment: Your css could be causing trouble.

Comment: I agree with @Teepeemm. We need more code to help...

Comment: I didn't use any css

Comment: seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/3L8bvg4t/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong, it just looks that way in display. I've added a second  element named "term2" in example below, and you can clearly see the elements  are seperated. I'm sure it will look much more decent once you style it properly.

[image: Example]

Comment: my question was: why is the list not tabbed under term 1 description like in the example picture

Comment: They don't align unless you want them to, that is just the way HTML works by default. You can take care of it in your stylesheet, or you can add "&nbsp;" character entity to the beginning of your <dt> elements. Fİve of "&nbsp;" will do the work to allign them